# Drawing lines in Java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Alright, so I am having a problem writing this program. I have the first part done but I don't know how to finish it. I've tried different solutions and everything, but yet I still have no clue. Here is what I have so far. What I need to do is make this where it will start in all four corners.

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    super.paintComponent( g );
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int number, x, y, dx, dy;
    x = 0;
    y = height;
    number = 15;
    dx = width / number;
    dy = height / number;
    for ( int i = 1; i < number; i++ )
    {
        x += dx;
        y -= dy;
        g.drawLine( 0, 0, x, y );
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls indent properly your code, and rewrite your question. The first two lines say nothing, and the meat phrase "What I need to do"... is hard to understand

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JComponent/JPanel inside JFrame, then your question will be answerable

Comment: You didn´t say what your problem is, what you are trying to acomplish.

Comment: You are lucky that some folks are able to guess what you're trying to do. Next time, please tell us. Don't assume that we all have ESP superpowers because unfortunately only a select few here do.

Comment: It's indented properly on mine? That's weird. Sorry about the grammar and such, I'm kind of in a hurry.

Comment: If you're in a hurry, then please *ask a decent question*. Please fill in the details! Your is a terribly incomplete question.

Comment: It's indented properly because I edited your original posting. The problem is not the grammar -- it's the lack of description of what you are trying to accomplish. For my answer below, I guessed at something based on your code, but only you know whether I guessed correctly. In the future, please describe what your code is intended to do, what it actually does, and where you're stuck in fixing it. You're more likely to get useful responses.

Answer (score 2):

I gather that you want to draw a fan-out of 15 lines from each corner to the facing diagonal. I'd suggest writing a routine to draw a fan from a point to an arbitrary line segment and then use that:

```
drawFan(Graphics g,
        int number,     // number of fan lines
        int x0, int y0, // coordinates of the point
        int sx, int sy, // coordinates of the line segment start
        int ex, int ey) // coordinates of the line segment end
{
    int x = sx,
        y = sy,
        dx = (ex - sx) / number,
        dy = (ey - sy) / number;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; ++i) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        g.drawLine(x0, y0, x, y);
    }
}
```

You can then call this with the appropriate values for each corner and diagonal.

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    super.paintComponent( g );
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    drawFan(g, 15, 0, 0, 0, height, width, 0);          // top left corner
    drawFan(g, 15, 0, height, 0, 0, width, height);     // bottom left corner
    drawFan(g, 15, width, height, 0, height, width, 0); // bottom right corner
    drawFan(g, 15, width, 0, 0, 0, width, height);      // top right corner
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, my suggestion is to understand how the coordinate system works in Java then It'll be easy.

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int widthX = getWidth();
    int heightY = getHeight();

    int num, i, j;
    num = 15;
    i = 0;
    j = 15;

    while( i != 16 && j != -1 ){

        g.drawLine( 0, 0, widthX*i/num, heightY*j/num );
        g.drawLine(  widthX*i/num, heightY*j/num, widthX, heightY );
        g.drawLine(  widthX*i/num, heightY*i/num,  widthX, 0);
        g.drawLine(  widthX*j/num, heightY*j/num,  0, heightY);

        i++;
        j--;

    }//end while 
}//end method paintComponent
```